# Solr: store original file offset or record number with token

Tags: indexing, data-structures, solr, lucene, token

I have a workflow where there is a layer of pre-processing in order to extract fields - this is later handed to another process to be ingested into Solr. The original files comprise documents with records, think tabular data. 
Some of these columns are indexed in Solr in order to get the relevant documentID for that value of the field. I.e. you query like

```
q=indexedField:indexedValue1 
fl= documentId
```

and have a response like:

```
... response: {documentID1, documentID3}
```

assuming indexedValue1 is present in field indexedField in documents documentID1, documentID3.

Each record will then have a value on one of the fields we want to index. The pre-processing concats these values to one (long) text field, with each value as a token, so you can later search by them. Indexed fields when handed to Morphlines look like this:
    
        ...
        value1 value2 ... valueN
        ...

Some fields are extracted and then regrouped in a field, so if you want to search by a value, you can know in which document it is.

(fairly simple until here)

However, how could I also store in Solr, along with each token that I want to search by, the offset (or record number) on the original file? The problem is not to extract this information (that is another problem, but we can solve it).

i.e. you would query like above, but will get per each document ID, the original record number or file offset where the record is located - something like:

```
... response:{ {documentID1, [1234, 5678]}, { documentID3, [] } }
```

Is this possible at all? In that case, what's the correct Solr data structure to efficiently model it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that what you are looking for is [Payloads](https://lucidworks.com/2014/06/13/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/). This functionality is present in Solr, but often requires custom code to actually fully benefit from it.

The challenge however would be that you seem to want to return payloads that are associated with the tokens that matched during search. That's even more complicated as the search focuses on returning **documents** and extracting what matched in the specific document is a separate challenge, usually solved by highlighters.

Comment: I think that given the problem itself, what I was thinking of doing would be an inverted-index abuse. I went with separate collections for separate kinds of information.
I accept you answer nevertheless, since it pointed me to the direction where to keep investigating within the Solr frame as the question asked.